# Unity trail renderer - minimum length

Tags: unity-game-engine, renderer

Is there a way to force the trail renderer to emit a short trail when standing still? Like a minimum length?

I tried to set the trailRenderer.time to different values, but that does not alter the behaviour when standing still.

Comment: while you are not moving in which direction would the trail point then? ;) I think you could just have a line renderer instead and use it as the minimum trail. Then let you trail renderer start there where the line ends

Comment: That actually worked quite well! Thank you!